# NoClassDefFoundError thrown when specifying same jar file at compile and run time

Tags: java, classpath

Hi I'm trying to use an external Java package from my own code and keep getting `NoClassDefFoundError` even though I am using the same class path that I compiled with.

For your amusement I have included a bare bones reproduction of what will undoubtedly be a dumb mistake on my part (I've been at this for about 6 hours so far)

```
/* WTF/WTF.java */  
import foo.Bar;  
class WTF  
{
    public static void main(String[] args)  
    {  
        Bar dontCare = new Bar();  
    }
}  

/* WTF/foo/Bar.java */  
package foo;  

class Bar  
{  
    public Bar() {}  
}
```

Now from the WTF directory I run the following:

```
javac foo/Bar.java              [ok]  
javac WTF.java                  [ok]  
java WTF                        [ok]  
jar cf foo.jar foo              [ok]
```

I remove the WTF/foo directory so there is only WTF/foo.jar available.

```
javac WTF.java -cp foo.jar      [ok]  
java WTF -cp foo.jar            [$!@#$!]
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: foo/Bar
    at WTF.main(WTF.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: foo.Bar
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
```

Any clues greatly appreciated!

Comment: I wonder if this even compiled!

Comment: My mistake Bar was marked public in my test file but I missed it when writing the listing - apart from that yes it does compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory where is `WTF.class` should be in the classpath.
Also, `Bar` should be public.

```
java -cp foo.jar:. WTF
```

`:` is the path separator in Linux, if you are using Windows replace it with `;`.

Comment: Not it, according to the error message `WTF` is found, but not `foo.Bar`.

Comment: @christoffer: yes, but the classpath argument must be before the main class name and I think the current directory should be in it

Answer (score 1):

Wrong arguments sequence? Try:

```
java -cp foo.jar WTF
```

Comment: Sounds like it. The parameters after the main classname are parameters to the program. But it should be `java -cp .:foo.jar WTF` to include the local directory if it contains `WTF.class`.